# How to pass data from view controller to UICollectionReusableView

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uiviewcontroller

I have 2 viewcontrollers (A and B). When i click on selected record in VC A, it will redirect to VC B. In my VC B, i have UICollectionReusableView to display header for details.

May i know how to pass data from VC A to VC B UICollectionReusableView? Attached herewith my code :-

**VC A (I able to get value in NSLog here)**

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];

    Merchant_TableViewCell *cell=[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

    //Link to Shop page
    MerchantDetail_ViewController *MerchantDetail_ViewControl = [[MerchantDetail_ViewController alloc] init];

    MerchantDetail_HeadView *MerchantDetail_Head = [[MerchantDetail_HeadView alloc] init];

    MerchantDetail_Head.strName = cell.nameLabel.text;
    NSLog(@"strname - %@",MerchantDetail_Head.strName);


    [self.navigationController pushViewController:MerchantDetail_ViewControl animated:YES];

}
```

**In VC B UICollectionReusableView .h file**

```
@interface MerchantDetail_HeadView : UICollectionReusableView

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet NSString *strName;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet NSString *strImage;
```

**In VC B UICollectionReusableView .m file (NSLog here will get null value)**

```
- (void)awakeFromNib {
    [super awakeFromNib];

    self.headImageButton.clipsToBounds = YES;
    self.headImageButton.layer.cornerRadius = 30;

    self.nickNameLabel.text = strName;
    NSLog(@"Head View - %@",strName);
}
```

Any idea? Please help thx.

Comment: Can you try using awakeAfterUsingCoder: and see what it prints?

Comment: Hi Vin, you mean is add in self.nickNameLabel.text = strName; in awakeAfterUsingCoder and check the result?

Comment: Yes add the log comment and check if it prints in awakeAfterUsingCoder

Comment: **IBOutlet** for `NSString` , what actually you trying to do?

Comment: Hi dahiya_boy, i want to pass the string to my collectionview and display it out as label

Comment: Hi Vin, is it correct for this code? - (void)awakeAfterUsingCoder {
    self.nickNameLabel.text = strName;
    NSLog(@"awakeAfterUsingCoder - %@",strName);
}